# How to get Edittext data using Context Menu?

Tags: android, android-intent, contextmenu, android-edittext

I want to get EditText value using Context Menu option by clicking on "EDIT". My Code:

This is context menu option I have created, code:

```
case R.id.Edit_Note:

                 Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Add_Task.class);
                 Cursor cursor = (Cursor) this.getListAdapter().getItem((int) info.id);
                 cursor.moveToPosition(itemPosition);
                 int content = cursor.getInt(0);
                 intent2.putExtra("content", content );
                 startActivity(intent2);

                break;
```

This is from where I am getting Intent:

```
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Listname);
    Title_Edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title_Edit);

    content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    Content_Edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.content_Edit);

    duedate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.duedate);

    duedatetext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.duedatetext);


    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Listname);
    title_Edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title_Edit);

    content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    content_Edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.content_Edit);

    duedate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.duedate);

    duedatetext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.duedatetext);

    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    int allcontent = intent2.getIntExtra("Content", 0);

    System.out.println(allcontent + "Intent ID");

    Database_Notepad db = new Database_Notepad(Add_Task.this);

     Cursor c = db.GetNote(allcontent);

     title_Edit.setText(c.getString(0));
     content_Edit.setText(c.getString(1));
     duedatetext.setText(c.getShort(2));
```

I am getting error: `cursorIndexoutofbound`:

```
Index 0 requested with a size of 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
 int allcontent = intent2.getIntExtra("content", 0);
```

instead of

```
 int allcontent = intent2.getIntExtra("Content", 0);
```

because you are sending value in Intent with `content` key but trying to get it using `Content`